# Problem when running cardano node on aws

Tags: cardano-node

i have troubles running the cardano node on aws.
After downloading the node config files and running the node, i get this failure:

***AesonException "Error in $: parsing PartialNodeConfiguration failed, expected Object, but encountered String"
cardano-node: Aeson exception:
Error in $: parsing PartialNodeConfiguration failed, expected Object, but encountered String***

Could someone help me how to solve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Few questions: Are you following a tutorial? Is this for testnet or mainnet? Did you change the config files any after you downloaded them? I believe there is an issue in one of your config files's syntax.

Comment: Additional to Anton questions, what is the command you're using to run the node?

Comment: I am following the official tutorial. I am running the mainnet. Here are the files:
curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/8111119/download/1/mainnet-topology.json
curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/8111119/download/1/mainnet-shelley-genesis.json
curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/8111119/download/1/mainnet-config.json
curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/8111119/download/1/mainnet-byron-genesis.json
curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/8111119/download/1/mainnet-alonzo-genesis.json

Comment: Here is the command to run the node: 
cardano-node run \
  --topology /home/ec2-user/cardano/mainnet-topology.json \
  --database-path /home/ec2-user/cardano/db \
  --socket-path /home/ec2-user/cardano/db/node.socket \
  --host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
  --port 3001 \
  --config /home/ec2-user/cardano/mainnet-config.json

Comment: I have also tried to download the same files as the tutorial but i become als the same failure:curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/7370192/download/1/mainnet-config.json
curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/7370192/download/1/mainnet-byron-genesis.json
curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/7370192/download/1/mainnet-shelley-genesis.json
curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/7370192/download/1/mainnet-alonzo-genesis.json
curl -O -J http://hydra.iohk.io/build/7370192/download/1/mainnet-topology.json

Comment: And as another information, i have successfully run the node locally on my mac machine with these configuration Files. But i have a trouble just on the aws ec2 linux instance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, i got the solution. When downloading the files directly using curl or wget command, i go the parsing error.

So i created the files manually using the touch command and inserted the content of the configuration with copy paste using vim linux command. It looks strange but it works like this.

Also i have done the same thing on my mac machine.